# React with webpack, "bootstrap.bundle.js Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined" - popper

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, popper.js

So we are transitioning to react and we use webpack, and we have some serious problems with popper. I've tried to use bootstrap.bundle.js to avoid the problem, but it didn't help.

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');
const htmlWebpackPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
      htmlWebpackPlugin,
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: "jquery",
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery"
      })
  ]
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "asdf",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.14.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
  }
}
```

And here I import bootstrap in the root js file

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from './components';
import 'jquery/dist/jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js';

render((
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Page compiles and works fine, the issue occurs when we press the dropdown, which code looks like this

```
<li className={classNames(bootstrap['nav-item'], [bootstrap.dropdown])}>
                                    <a className={classNames(bootstrap['nav-link'], bootstrap['dropdown-toggle'])} 
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button"
                                    aria-haspopup="true"
                                    aria-expanded="false">
                                        Problem Sets
                                    </a>
                                    <div className={bootstrap['dropdown-menu']} role="list" aria-label="Problem Sets">
                                        <a className={bootstrap['dropdown-item']}>Problem Set 01</a>
                                        <a className={bootstrap['dropdown-item']}>Problem Set 02</a>
                                        <a className={bootstrap['dropdown-item']}>Problem Set 03</a>
                                        <a className={bootstrap['dropdown-item']}>Upload</a>
                                        <input id='fileid' type='file' hidden/>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

The issue we get is:
[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35odF.png)
[code error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJkCY.png)

So it seems like it cannot find the popper, although we use bundled bootstrap js which should have poopper in it as far as my understanging goes.
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Popper to your plugins in Webpack:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ // inject ES5 modules as global vars
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: 'popper.js',
    }),
],
```

Comment: (you may also need to try as `popper: 'popper.js'` depending on what you use in your code)

Comment: Unfortunately none of those did help